# Possible to see passwords on db browser for sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

So I have a wiki site made with python using flask. In the site you have to register to submit a post. When I made my account I looked at the db file. Under users it has my username but my password looks something like this

pbkdf2:sha256:50000$trQqtDeG$fb666b434b1920c814101fd3afedf75c9e21e2eebbfe7e6aa9fe4aec3d69b1e3

I made my password poop ( dont ask why lol ) but thats what it comes up as. Lets say if I were to oneday forget my password, how can I check to see what it is?

Edit: Thanks for the explanation ! :)

Comment: You can't.  Any site doing it correctly is hashing passwords (using a one-way hash) and then using that value to compare to user input (user input gets hashed, then compared)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. This is a one way hash, and it's meant to be that way - it's a common practice not to store plaintext passwords on the database, so that nobody can ever see what is the users password.

The general concept is that given an user password (and a salt) you are able to compute the same hash value and compare it to see if the password is correct, but you are not able to (easily) get the password by obtaining the hash.

To deal with 'what if I forget my password' issue you should implement a password reset procedure.